# Wireguard not working with enpoint included in AllowedIps

Tags: wireguard

I run a wireguard enpoint as a docker container on my server with roadwarrior clients connecting to it via LTE:

[image: wireguard network diagram]

The real server address is a static public IP. The client config is as follows (irrelevant parts excluded):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.254.99.2

[Peer]
AllowedIps = 10.254.99.1/32
Endpoint = 192.168.5.55
```

This works fine if I ping the client from within the docker container. But since I also want to reach the client from the docker host, I add a route on the server:

```
ip route add 10.254.99.0/24 via 172.17.0.2 dev docker0 src 192.168.5.55
```

Accordingly, I add the `src` address to the list of AllowedIps on the server:

```
[Peer]
AllowedIps = 10.254.99.1/32, 192.168.5.55/32
```

And with this things stop working. I cannot ping the client, neither from the server nor from within the container anymore. If I allow all Ips on the client instead, everything works as expected:

```
[Peer]
AllowedIps = 0.0.0.0/0
```

But I don't want to route all traffic through the tunnel. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: multiple issues at once. `Endpoint = 192.168.5.55`. Does that mean you're attempting to tunnel 192.168.5.55 inside of the tunnel envelopped within 192.168.5.55 ?

Comment: I don't intend to but I guess that's what I'm doing. I only want to allow traffic originating from 192.168.5.55 through wg. Not sure why this works with 0.0.0.0/0 in allowed IPs though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the same address in the client's `Endpoint` and `AllowedIPs` settings*. `Endpoint` should be the server's address *outside* the tunnel, and `AllowedIPs` should include all the addresses you want to have access *inside* the tunnel.

To fix it, get rid of the `src` setting on the route you added to the server, so that the route will just use the address of the server's `docker0` interface:

```
ip route add 10.254.99.0/24 via 172.17.0.2 dev docker0
```

Then change the WireGuard client's `AllowedIPs` setting to include the address of the server's `docker0` interface  (`172.17.0.1`):

```
AllowedIps = 10.254.99.1/32, 172.17.0.1/32
```

Your server will now use its `docker0` interface address (`172.17.0.1`) as the source of the packets it sends through your WireGuard network.

---

However, instead of adding that extra layer of routing on your server, the simplest thing to do would be to run the WireGuard container in "host" network mode (using the [`--network=host`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) flag with `docker run`, or the [`network_mode: host`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode) setting with `docker-compose`). That would expose the WireGuard container's `wg0` interface directly to the host, so you wouldn't need additional routing rules on the server, and you wouldn't need to add additional `AllowedIPs` to the client.

In that case, the server would just use the WireGuard interface's own `10.254.99.1` address as the source of the packets it sends through your WireGuard network.

---

* unless you set up some fancy packet routing/filtering rules on your client instead of using the defaults the WireGuard client sets up for you

Comment: "You can't use the same address in the client's Endpoint and AllowedIPs settings." Why does it work when AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0? That CIDR covers the Endpoint.

Comment: `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` works because the WireGuard client special-cases `/0` to set up some fancy packet routing/filtering rules for you. Start here for an explanation of how wg-quick handles this on Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70827884/149050

Comment: Thanks! The details with the **network interface of the docker** was a life saver! I think it should be added as a note to the official documentation!