# Prevent routing loop with FwMark in Wireguard

Tags: routing, wireguard, policy-routing

I want to set up a VPN server so that the VPN connection is used only when accessing resources within the server. Normally, I'd do this by using the server's internal IP, but I want to use the domain name to access this server.

There are a few ways to achieve this:

1. Use a custom DNS server
2. Bind another IP to this server
3. Set `Endpoint` to be the same as `AllowedIPs` in the "client" (I'm aware that wg doesnt use server-client architecture, but it's easier for me to understand this way). E.g:

   ```ini
   # client
   [Interface]
   PrivateKey = ...
   Address = 10.0.0.2/24

   [Peer]
   PublicKey = ...
   AllowedIPs = 1.2.3.4/32
   Endpoint = 1.2.3.4:51820
   ```

Long story short, option 3 works the best for my use case, but it would cause a loop in the routing table. After doing some research ("Improved Rule-based Routing" section in [wireguard page](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/) and [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/1083431/1059321)), I learned that using `FwMark` in the "server" config could resolve the issue.

So I came up with this:

```ini
# server
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
FwMark = 51820

PostUp = ip route add default dev wg0 table 2468
PostUp = ip rule add not fwmark 51820 table 2468

PostDown = ip route del default dev wg0 table 2468
PostDown = ip rule del not fwmark 51820 table 2468

[Peer]
...
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work (both the VPN and direct communication gets timed out, so I'm guessing I've messed up the routing rule) My questions are:

1. Why doesn't this work?
2. Does setting `FwMark = 51820` in the "server" config marks VPN routed packets? Or do I need something like `PostUp = wg set wg0 fwmark 51820`?
3. What happens if I replace `2468` with `default`, `main`, or even `local`? I guess I don't understand why the official doc had to set a new table for this.

Thanks

EDIT: Fix typo with the port

Comment: You want to route the payload with the same address as the envelope. That's not unheard of (eg: IPSec is often configured to do this). But beside obvious errors (eg: client's peer (aka server) endpoint on port 50102 while server's config is 51820) and of course the non-obvious problems, you have to understand that both the client and the server require adequate routing changes. Not only the server. Currently you don't appear to think the client requires something. It does, just as the server.

Comment: Yet there's a difference between client and server: client is the querier (and presents a random endpoint), server is the responder. This might affect how the very first packet can be handled best on both sides. Then UDP on a multi-homed system can have problems. If the server keeps 10.0.0.1 set, chances are some UDP services will reply with the wrong address to an UDP query from the client.

Comment: Now that youve pointed out, I think it make sense that both the server and the client requires routing changes. I'm guessing the client also needs routing rule changes, but I'm still unsure what that looks like.

Comment: No worries. Could you help me understand the problem of setting the server IP as 10.0.0.1? I don't really see how this could cause any UDP services to reply with the wrong address.

Comment: For UDP it's an independent issue not about WireGuard that can always happen with UDP services on multi-homed systems. For example check this Q/A : https://serverfault.com/questions/1137790/libvirt-udp-not-working-between-host-and-vm  or this one (search for "Caveat: UDP service" in my answer): https://serverfault.com/questions/1130454/allowing-a-route-to-from-network-when-there-are-multiple-networks . multihomed + UDP always requires application support (in code or configuration) *in addition* to adequate routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

There are two commands: `wg` the low-level WireGuard ("WG") command that only affects a `type wireguard` interface's settings (including setting a mark for outgoing envelope traffic), and `wg-quick` which in addition will configure addresses, routes, and sometimes routing rules, additional routing tables, and even *nftables* rules to tie all this together.

1. this answer will explain how to make it work
2. `FwMark = 51820` marks the outgoing envelope (not the payload).

   The adequate `wg` command will be run when this parameter is set.
3. `Table =`  tells `wg-quick` where to add routes.

   - When not provided, the default is `Table = auto`. It behaves like `Table = main` unless there's also `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` (or `AllowedIPs = ::/0` for IPv6) which completely changes the behavior with additional routing table, routing rules, marks and *nftables* (or *iptables* if *nftables* is not installed) rules. This altered behavior is what allows full tunneling VPN (rather than split VPN) configuration to work properly. I give an example later.
   - If `Table = off` then `wg-quick` won't touch routes at all. This will all have to be handled by the administrator (and possibly with `PreUp/PostUp` rules).
   - Other useful cases are to pick an arbitrary table that will be reused later with custom routing rules. This answer will use `Table = 2468` on the client. `wg-quick` will add routes to this routing table instead of the `main` routing table. An other choice could have been to use `Table = off` and add any relevant route with `PostUp` entries.
   - The `local` routing table should be left alone. It's populated by the kernel and is handling local routes related to addresses assigned on the system for incoming traffic destined to this system, including broadcasts.
   - the `default` routing table is almost never used and is empty in a standard setup. It's probably used in some routing daemons. It would only make sense to have entries in it if there was no default route in the `main` routing table, else this routing table would never have a chance to be reached with the default routing rules in place (`main`'s default route once found would stop the lookup).

The setup below assumes that the client is running Linux, has *nftables* installed and its main interface (which will be named `eth0`) or actually all its interfaces have [Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2) ("SRPF") enabled (sysctl [`net.conf.ipv4.all.rp_filter=1`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1555)). *nftables* rules below, including in the *Corner cases for the client* paragraph, are used only to have envelope *incoming* traffic be marked adequately in order to be seen as using the correct route and succeed at the SRPF check. Should no such setup be enabled or at least the main interface (`eth0`) set to [Loose RPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.4) (`net.conf.ipv4.eth0.rp_filter=2`) then the whole *nftables* parts can be ignored. It then doesn't matter anymore if *incoming* packets used the wrong path: they were received and will be used by the routing stack instead of being dropped. Any part below dealing with *nftables* will thus assume that this is in place on the client:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
```

There's one case already handled by `wg-quick` that also accounts for `rp_filter=1` where the payload address has to be distinguished from the envelope address which is a remote address using the default route: when using the default setting `Table = auto` and `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0`, which is usual on a client deployment. Then `wg-quick` uses a firewall mark and additional *nftables* rules for this case. It would appear like this:

```shell
# wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.0.0.2/24 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
# ip route show table 51820
default dev wg0 scope link 
# nft list table ip wg-quick-wg0
table ip wg-quick-wg0 {
    chain preraw {
        type filter hook prerouting priority raw; policy accept;
        iifname != "wg0" ip daddr 10.0.0.2 fib saddr type != local drop
    }

    chain premangle {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        meta l4proto udp meta mark set ct mark
    }

    chain postmangle {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        meta l4proto udp meta mark 0x0000ca6c ct mark set meta mark
    }
}
```

The firewall mark set by WG for outgoing traffic allows to distinguish (outgoing) envelope traffic from (outgoing) payload traffic in routing rules.

The *nftables* part is for handling envelope's reply/incoming traffic:

- chronologically 1st, it updates in the *postrouting* hook the *conntrack* flow to the mark set by WG for *outgoing* envelope traffic.
- then, in the *prerouting* hook this mark is retrieved back from the saved *conntrack* flow entry to mark incoming reply envelope traffic
- the early prerouting hook (`preraw`) is to prevent receiving non-WG traffic to the address set on the WG interface (not for routing, but security, won't be retained below)

These *nftables* rules allow in the end to have incoming envelope traffic seen as envelope traffic in routing rules. Along [`src_valid_mark=1`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1576) all this effort is to have traffic not fail SRPF.

Because `wg-quick`'s bash code triggers it only for `Table = auto` + `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0`,
this will have to be adapted and done manually on the client (and that's also the *filtering rules* part of the `*` remark at the end of [OP's linked Q/A's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1083431/1059321): *unless you set up some fancy packet routing/filtering rules on your client instead of using the defaults the WireGuard client sets up for you*).

### Configurations on client and server

client's `/etc/wireguard/wg0.nft` which will be loaded from `wg0.conf`:

```
table ip wg-quick-wg0        # for idempotence
delete table ip wg-quick-wg0 # for idempotence

table ip wg-quick-wg0 {
    chain postmangle {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        meta l4proto udp meta mark 1234 ct mark set meta mark
    }

    chain premangle {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        meta l4proto udp meta mark set ct mark
    }
}
```

client's `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` (referencing the previous file):

```ini
[Interface]
PrivateKey = clientprivkey
FwMark = 1234
Table = 2468
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
# setting it on eth0 would have been enough
PreUp = sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
PreUp = nft -f /etc/wireguard/wg0.nft
PostUp = ip -4 rule add not fwmark 1234 table 2468
# not actually needed for OP's current setup, but won't hurt 
PostUp = ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
# wg-quick probably already deleted the table because of the chosen name but just in case...
PostDown = nft delete table wg-quick-wg0 2>/dev/null || true

[Peer]
PublicKey = serverpubkey
AllowedIPs = 1.2.3.4/32
Endpoint = 1.2.3.4:51820
# needed if client is behind NAT and can receive server-initiated WG traffic
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Assuming below the client's current IP address on its main interface `eth0` is (NAT-ed...) 192.168.1.2/24 with a gateway 192.168.1.1 here's what would be the outcome for various routing decisions:

```shell
# # outgoing payload
# ip route get 1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4 dev wg0 table 2468 src 10.0.0.2 uid 0 
    cache 
# # outgoing envelope: mark is set directly by WG
# ip route get 1.2.3.4 mark 1234
1.2.3.4 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.2 mark 0x4d2 uid 0 
    cache 

# # incoming payload
# ip route get from 1.2.3.4 iif wg0 to 10.0.0.2
local 10.0.0.2 from 1.2.3.4 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif wg0 
# # incoming envelope without mark: doesn't happen thanks to nftables. Would be rejected by SRPF
# ip route get from 1.2.3.4 iif eth0 to 192.168.1.2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device link
# # incoming envelope: reply envelope traffic mark is set by nftables from conntrack entry
# ip route get from 1.2.3.4 iif eth0 to 192.168.1.2 mark 1234
local 192.168.1.2 from 1.2.3.4 dev lo table local mark 0x4d2 
    cache <local> iif eth0
```

The server setup is much simpler because its own endpoint is a known configuration and the client's payload address within WG is a non-routable address over Internet and won't clash with the client's envelope address. No *nftables* involved on the server.

server's `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`:

```ini
[Interface]
PrivateKey = serverprivkey
ListenPort = 51820
#no address set on wg0

[Peer]
PublicKey = clientpubkey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2
```

If this server's main interface `eth0` has address 1.2.3.4/24 and a gateway of 1.2.3.1/24 with a remote WG peer (client) discovered as 192.0.2.2:45678 when it reached the server, the various routing cases, all simple, are:

```shell
# # outgoing payload 
# ip route get 10.0.0.2
10.0.0.2 dev wg0 src 1.2.3.4 uid 0 
    cache 
# # outgoing envelope
# ip route get 192.0.2.2
192.0.2.2 via 1.2.3.1 dev eth0 src 1.2.3.4 uid 0 
    cache 

# # incoming payload
# ip route get from 10.0.0.2 iif wg0 1.2.3.4
local 1.2.3.4 from 10.0.0.2 dev lo 
    cache <local> iif wg0 
# # incoming envelope
# ip route get from 192.0.2.2 iif eth0 1.2.3.4
local 1.2.3.4 from 192.0.2.2 dev lo 
    cache <local> iif eth0
```

No address was added on `wg0` to prevent the usual UDP multi-homed complication. Had this address been added, the source address to reach 10.0.0.2 would have been chosen as 10.0.0.1, thus triggering issues for multi-homed-unaware UDP services answering through the tunnel: UDP replies to queries made to 1.2.3.4 would use 10.0.0.1 as source which would be rejected by the client application (and even before this, dropped by its WG interface since 10.0.0.1 is not allowed). Additional details in these Q/A where I made an answer:

- SF: [Libvirt - UDP not working between host and VM](https://serverfault.com/questions/1137790/libvirt-udp-not-working-between-host-and-vm)
- UL SE: [Server does not respond to ping - ICMP is received and nothing happens](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589048/server-does-not-respond-to-ping-icmp-is-received-and-nothing-happens/589133#589133) (search for *Caveat: UDP services*)

The best way to never encounter an UDP multi-homed problem is to actually *not* be in the multi-homed case and not add an IP address on `wg0`. Source address selection algorithm will select the "main" IP address instead when it can't select an address from `wg0`. Should the server be already multi-homed and somehow the wrong source address selected, then it's possible to fix the route added by `wg-quick` with this additional entry on server's `wg0.conf`:

```
PostUp = ip route replace 10.0.0.2/32 dev wg0 src 1.2.3.4
```

which will hint the address selection algorithm to use 1.2.3.4 as source to reach 10.0.0.2. This could also allow to set 10.0.0.1 on `wg0` even if it won't be used and change this kind of route for the whole /24 then in case of multiple peers for example with this instead of above:

```
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PostUp = ip route replace 10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 src 1.2.3.4
```

This route change won't survive or follow something affecting the actual 1.2.3.4 (eg: main interface administratively set down then up). Actually one can just add "again" 1.2.3.4 on `wg0`. For example instead of above (be sure it's as a /32 so it won't trigger the creation of any additional routes causing network disruption):

```
Address = 1.2.3.4/32
```

This is for the server as an end node. If it's acting as router and routing traffic (eg: containers or VMs) rather than generating it itself, then there's no UDP multi-homed issue, but chances are that settings to handle this router case will be missing anyway.

### Corner cases for the client

If not using SRPF (`rp_filter=1`) on the client then just as all other *nftables* settings, applying the fixes below is not needed.

There are corner cases on the client when bypassing WG to reach the server with an adequate application able to use `setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_MARK, ...)`

- traceroute (--udp)

  Need to *traceroute* toward the server through the actual Internet to figure out what network outage is going on?

  ```
  traceroute -n --fwmark=1234 1.2.3.4
  ```

  This will still timeout right before displaying the target because expected return traffic isn't UDP but a related ICMP error: no mark set and rejected by SRPF. Can be fixed by adding a rule marking *related* traffic:

  ```
  nft add rule ip wg-quick-wg0 premangle ct state related ct mark 1234 meta mark set ct mark
  ```
- ping, other traceroutes, socat with TCP...

  ```
  ping -n -m 1234 1.2.3.4
  traceroute -n --icmp --fwmark=1234 1.2.3.4
  socat exec:'echo foo' TCP4:1.2.3.4:3333,setsockopt-listen=1:36:L1234
  ```

  Also systematically mark and retrieve conntrack flow's mark, not just for UDP:

  ```
  nft add rule ip wg-quick-wg0 postmangle meta mark 1234 ct mark set meta mark
  nft add rule ip wg-quick-wg0 premangle ct mark 1234 meta mark set ct mark
  ```

  This makes the 3 commands above work instead of having a timeout.